# Python Pygame text overlay printing on top of itself each time

Tags: python, linux, pygame, pygame-surface, pygame-clock

I'm currently wanting to use an old piece of Python code called python slideshow with time and weather (github). I'm using a Raspberry Pi and I've got it all setup and it works perfectly in landscape (normal) mode. This is a slideshow application which has a weather and time overlay developed on Pygame.

I want to use the application in portrait, however when I rotate my screen in the /boot/config.txt using display_rotate=1 (or 3) and restart the slideshow, everything appears to work, the weather overlay appears in the bottom left/right as it should, however as soon as any part of the weather or clock or day update, it prints the text over itself.

Has anyone got an idea of what might be causing this behaviour? I can't see anything in the code. Here's the python file from Git below and I have attached a screenshot of the strange behavour[image showing text overlay issue in the clock in this instance[][1]](https://github.com/andrewdelph/python-slideshow-with-time-and-weather/blob/master/ss.py):
[Python slideshow with time and weather on github](https://github.com/andrewdelph/python-slideshow-with-time-and-weather/blob/master/ss.py)

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
    """
    A pygame program to show a slideshow of all images buried in a given directory.
    Originally Released: 2007.10.31 (Happy halloween!)
    """
    from __future__ import division
    import argparse
    import os
    import stat
    import sys
    import time
    import datetime


    import pygame
    from pygame.locals import QUIT, KEYDOWN, K_ESCAPE


    #weather
    import pyowm



    file_list = []  # a list of all images being shown
    title = "pgSlideShow | My Slideshow!"  # caption of the window...
    waittime = 5   # default time to wait between images (in seconds)


    def walktree(top, callback):
        """recursively descend the directory tree rooted at top, calling the
        callback function for each regular file. Taken from the module-stat
        example at: http://docs.python.org/lib/module-stat.html
        """
        for f in os.listdir(top):
            pathname = os.path.join(top, f)
            mode = os.stat(pathname)[stat.ST_MODE]
            if stat.S_ISDIR(mode):
                # It's a directory, recurse into it
                walktree(pathname, callback)
            elif stat.S_ISREG(mode):
                # It's a file, call the callback function
                callback(pathname)
            else:
                # Unknown file type, print a message
                print 'Skipping %s' % pathname


    def addtolist(file, extensions=['.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.bmp']):
        """Add a file to a global list of image files."""
        global file_list  # ugh
        filename, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
        e = ext.lower()
        # Only add common image types to the list.
        if e in extensions:
            print 'Adding to list: ', file
            file_list.append(file)
        else:
            print 'Skipping: ', file, ' (NOT a supported image)'


    def input(events):
        """A function to handle keyboard/mouse/device input events. """
        for event in events:  # Hit the ESC key to quit the slideshow.
            if (event.type == QUIT or
                (event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE)):
                pygame.quit()


    def timeSince(lastTime,interval):
        if (time.time() - lastTime)>=interval:
            return True
        else:
            return False


    def main(startdir="."):
        global file_list, title, waittime
        lastSwitch=time.time()
        lastWeather=time.time()

        owm = pyowm.OWM('4cc9ae1d116c7e70c145252ab605f260')
        observation = owm.weather_at_place('Ottawa,CA')
        w = observation.get_weather()
        temperature=(w.get_temperature('celsius'))['temp']
        status=w.get_status()
        #print w

        pygame.init()

        # Test for image support
        if not pygame.image.get_extended():
            print "Your Pygame isn't built with extended image support."
            print "It's likely this isn't going to work."
            sys.exit(1)

        walktree(startdir, addtolist)  # this may take a while...
        if len(file_list) == 0:
            print "Sorry. No images found. Exiting."
            sys.exit(1)

        modes = pygame.display.list_modes()
        print max(modes)
        pygame.display.set_mode(max(modes))

        screen = pygame.display.get_surface()
        screen_width, screen_height= screen.get_size()
        pygame.display.set_caption(title)
        #pygame.display.toggle_fullscreen()
        pygame.display.set_mode(max(modes),pygame.FULLSCREEN)

        pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)

        #create font
        timeFont = pygame.font.Font("indulta/Indulta-SemiSerif-boldFFP.otf", 100)
        dateFont = pygame.font.Font("indulta/Indulta-SemiSerif-boldFFP.otf", 60)
        weatherFont = pygame.font.Font("indulta/Indulta-SemiSerif-boldFFP.otf", 60)

        print str(waittime) +"wait time"


        current = 0
        num_files = len(file_list)
        while(True):
            try:
                img = pygame.image.load(file_list[current])
                img = img.convert()
                tempX,tempY=img.get_size()
                ratio =tempX/tempY
                tempSize=(screen_width,int(screen_width/ratio))
                print str(img.get_size())+" to "+ str(tempSize) +"and ratio: "+str(ratio)
                # rescale the image to fit the current display
                img = pygame.transform.scale(img, tempSize)
                screen.blit(img, (0, 0))

                #gets current weather
                if timeSince(lastWeather,30):
                    observation = owm.weather_at_place('Ottawa,CA')
                    w = observation.get_weather()
                    temperature=(w.get_temperature('celsius'))['temp']
                    status=w.get_status()
                    print status
                    lastWeather=time.time()
                    print "updateing weather"

                #gets the current time and displays it
                timeText=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M%p")
                dateText=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%B %d, %Y")
                weatherText=str(int(temperature))+"`C  "+status


                timeLabel = timeFont.render(timeText, 1, (255,255,255))
                dateLabel = dateFont.render(dateText, 1, (255,255,255))
                weatherLabel = weatherFont.render(weatherText, 1, (255,255,255))

                timeWidth, timeHeight= timeLabel.get_size()
                dateWidth, dateHeight= dateLabel.get_size()
                weatherWidth, weatherHeight= weatherLabel.get_size()

                screen.blit(weatherLabel, (0, screen_height-weatherHeight))

                screen.blit(timeLabel, (screen_width-timeWidth, screen_height-timeHeight-dateHeight))
                screen.blit(dateLabel, (screen_width-dateWidth, screen_height-dateHeight))

                pygame.display.flip()

                input(pygame.event.get())
                time.sleep(1/60)
            except pygame.error as err:
                print "Failed to display %s: %s" % (file_list[current], err)
                sys.exit(1)

            # When we get to the end, re-start at the beginning
            if timeSince(lastSwitch,waittime):
                current = (current + 1) % num_files;
                lastSwitch=time.time()


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
            description='Recursively loads images '
            'from a directory, then displays them in a Slidshow.'
        )

        parser.add_argument(
            'path',
            metavar='ImagePath',
            type=str,
            default='.',
            nargs="?",
            help='Path to a directory that contains images'
        )
        parser.add_argument(
            '--waittime',
            type=int,
            dest='waittime',
            action='store',
            default=1,
            help='Amount of time to wait before showing the next image.'
        )
        parser.add_argument(
            '--title',
            type=str,
            dest='title',
            action='store',
            default="pgSlidShow | My Slideshow!",
            help='Set the title for the display window.'
        )
        args = parser.parse_args()
        #waittime = args.waittime

        title = args.title
        main(startdir=args.path)
```

Comment: You need to seriously trim your question down.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer. Adding the line `screen.fill((0,0,0))` just above `img = pygame.image.load(file_list[current])`has fixed the issue.